# Update objects - form NOT valid - having difficulties Django

Tags: python, django

I'am trying to Update existing objects from a database with a form. 
What I need to obtain is : 
     1 displaying the data to be modified, 2, change the data with the new ones 3, display the new one.

I managed step 1 but its a mystery for step 2. Could you give me a hand ?

Here is my code :

**Views.py**

`def modec(request, etatcivil_id):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render_to_response('cv/connexionrequired.html')

```
k = request.user.email

if request.method == 'POST':
    ec = Etatcivil.objects.get(id=etatcivil_id)
    form = EtatCivilForm(data=request.POST, instance=ec)
    form.auteur=k
    print "Product Post"
    if form.has_changed():
        print "form has changed"
        if form.is_valid():
            print "Display Form"
            form.save(commit=False)
            fom.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/cv/creer')

else:
    eta = Etatcivil.objects.get(id= etatcivil_id)
    form = EtatCivilForm(eta.__dict__)
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('cv/modec.html', args)`
```

Model.py

```
    from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager

from django.conf import settings

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not username: username = email.split('@')[0]
        user = self.model(
            email= MyUserManager.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=cv._db)


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, db_index=True)
    registration = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('email', )



class Etatcivil(models.Model):
    Auteur = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 'email')
    Nom = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    Prenom = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    Date_de_Naissance = models.DateTimeField()
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    Telephone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Reseaux = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

and modec.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'cv/style/style.css' %}" />
<html style="width: 100%; min-width:50%;">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title> Créer votre CV</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <table>
                <tr style=" topmargin: 0px; leftmargin: 0px ">
                    <td style="padding: 0px; topmargin: 0px; leftmargin: 0px; width=70% ">
                        <img src=" {% static "cv/photos/logo.png" %}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="menutd">
                        <a style="color: #404040;" href="/cv/creer"> Enregistrer mes Informations </a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="menutd">
                        {% block content %}
                        <a style="color: #404040;" href="/cv/generer"> Generer un CV </a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="menutd">
                        <a style="color: #404040;" href="/login/off" align="left"> Deconnection </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </header>
        <div style=" width: 50%; Height: 100%; line-height: 100%; margin-top: 150px; margin-bottom: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;  vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; font-family: Helvetica Neue; font-size: 36px; color: #ffffff">
            <form action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in form %}
                <input type="{{ field.Charfield }}" name="{{ field.name }}" value="{{ field.value }}"> </input><br />
                {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" name="valider mon etat civil" value="Valider Article">
            </form>
            {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where do you think I am wrong ?

Thanks in advance..

EDIT: 
It appears that the form is not valid. Any idea ?

Comment: Have you read Django's form docs? They're very good, and actually explain how to doe almost exactly what you're after: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: Yes. What I want is to update / modify an already existing object. Not create a new one..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you think you need to pass the instance's `__dict__` attribute to the form when instantiating it. This is the cause of your problem, because the first parameter to a form is the `data` argument, and passing that makes the form bound - triggering validation, as the documentation explains in great detail.

Instead of doing that, you should do what you have correctly done in the POST block: pass the instance.

```
eta = Etatcivil.objects.get(id=etatcivil_id)
form = EtatCivilForm(instance=eta)
```

Also note you are doing some very strange things in the template (what is `{{ form.CharField }}` supposed to be?) but the one thing you are not doing is showing the form errors, which you should do - otherwise you won't know why the form is not valid. Again, all this is explained in great detail in the documentation.

Comment: i removed the '__dict__' but it still don't work. I also the form error, but no information are given.

Comment: It's not just removing dict, it's also ensuring that you use the instance keyword.

Comment: And you shouldn't redirect away unless the form is invalid. Once again, the docs show exactly the pattern to use to redisplay the form with errors.

Comment: I also did. Sorry... I'm new in coding. Thanks for your help anyway.